# Node.js how to handle drop down of server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On Node.js api there lots of `if`s and one can easily send request with some undefined var and crash the whole server until it re-starts again - something that could take up to 20 seconds.

I know that it should be checked if a variable is defined before working with it. But its very easy to forget something and keep working with an undefined var.

Is there a global definition to the server to avoid such of a drop down?

Comment: I think you should treat this as you would treat a security issue: code defensively and check your inputs.

Comment: Good ideas for reducing risk: use `eslint` during development and write good automatic tests

Comment: Also eslint is a great tool to enforce good practices.  A step further would be to use a typed language that compiles down to javascript like Nick mentioned.  Really though node is not much more volatile than other languages like c# or java in the sense that you are still responsible for defensive coding, and I don't think stumbling across an undefined property is any different from a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution I could think of is implementing a cluster, in which only one process will go down, not the whole server. You could also make the process to go up again automatically. [See more here](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Comment: Hey there thanks for the reply. I am facing problem using sockets with this kind of strategy. If one registered to worker1 and another registered to worker2, how the server will handle their sockets subscriptions?

Comment: If I understood correctly I think you're talking about workers not being able to talk to each other. One thing to keep in mind when programming in cluster, is that workers don't share memory. This means that if you have, for instance, a shared list and you add an element to it, it will be added just in that specific worker unless you tell the rest. If this is not a solution to your problem please write again. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

In any application there are a lot of "ifs" and assumptions. With JavaScript, being weakly typed and dynamic, you can really shoot yourself in the foot.

But the same rules apply here as any other language. Practice [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). That is, cover *all* the bases in each function and statement block.

You can also try out [programming Nodejs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter#typescript-node-starter) with [Typescript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript). It ads some static type checking and other nice features that help you miss your foot when you shoot. You can also use (I think) [Flow](https://flow.org/) to statically type check things. But these won't make you a better programmer.

One other suggestion is to design your system as a [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture). So that one portion going down doesn't necessarily affect others. "Microservices" being a subset of that.

Comment: I am working with Atom, could this one hint me when I am working with some variable that is even intend to be undefined?

Answer (score 1):

First, defensive programming and extensive testing are your friends.  Obviously, preventing an issue before it happens is much better than trying to react to it after it happens.

Second, there is no foolproof mechanism for catching all exceptions at some high level and then putting your server back into a known, safe state.  You just can't really do that in any complex server because you don't know what you were in the middle of when the exception happened.  People will often try to do this, but it's like proceeding with a wounded server that may have some messed up internals.  It's not safe or advisable.  If a problem was not intercepted (e.g. exception caught or error detected) at the level where it occurred by code that knows how to properly handle that situation, then the only completely safe path forward is to restart your server.

So, if after implementing as much defensive programming as you possibly can and testing the heck out of it, you still want to prevent end-user downtime from a server crash/restart, then the best way to do that is to assume that a given server process will occasionally need to be restarted and plan for that.

The simplest way to prevent end-user downtime when a server process restarts is to use **clustering** and thus have **multiple server processes** with some sort of load balancer that both monitors server processes and routes incoming connections among the healthy server processes.  When one server process is down, it is temporarily taken out of the rotation and other server processes can handle new, incoming connections.  When the failed server process is successfully restarted, it can be added back to the rotation and be used again for new requests.  Clustering in this way can be done within a single server (multiple processes on the same server) or across servers (multiple servers, each with server processes on them).

In some cases, this same process can even be used to roll out a new version of server code without any system downtime (doing this requires additional planning).

Comment: Why the downvote?  If a downvoter explains why they are downvoting, then the author has a chance to improve their answer, benefiting the whole community.  A downvote without any explanation is just like sending a child to the corner for 10 minutes, but not telling them why - doesn't do much good.

Comment: But what if someone is a mean user trying by purpose to shut your server down and easily run a scripts sending tons of request with bad input?
For example, he views the source of the page and sees that there is a request receiving this data: object1.object2.object3.object4 = "yes";
and he just sends object1.object3.object2.object4 = "yes"; and sends this tons of times and thats it, even if you had 200 clusters they all will be shutted down by queue anyway. do you understand what I mean?

Comment: BTW, I think stackoverflow should allow downvote only if the voter EXPLAINS WHY HE DID THIS.

Comment: @Raz - To protect against someone sending your server lots of data, you would implement "rate limiting".  That limits the number of requests you will accept from any single account (or IP address) per second or minute to something that a real use of your services would be perfectly fine with.  All the large services (such as Google) protect their services with rate limiting.  They also have many other protections against other forms of denial of service attacks.

Comment: This should be done in Node.js code or that I should go ask it to the my VPS provider?

Comment: @Raz - There are multiple ways to do it.  You can see what your provider offers.  There are node.js packages to assist also.  And, some load balancer hardware can do it.